# Eclipse doesn't show warning and error on xml files in android project

Tags: android, eclipse

[image]

I see warning and error icons on parent folders but I can't see them on actual xml files.
When I open the folder which contains the files, warnings on files blink for a sec and then disappear.
What can I do about this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you every file in anim folder???

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question well but warning on the anim folder is actually about the xmls in it. (unused, etc.). By the way I've editted the question above.

Comment: are you use `ADT16` than its `Lint error checking...`

Comment: Can I see the lint errors or warnings on files instead of folders?

Comment: I don't think the issue is about Lint checking. Because I don't see any warning in anim folder at "Lint View" when I launch complete Lint check.

Comment: open that anim folder and check any hidden files like .thumbs or etc...